# React native Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm having this error everytime creating a new app. I copy old package.json form my working project but gives me this error. How to fix it I tryed a lot. It gives error when my App.js is like this

Error

*Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.*
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

Giving error `App.js`

```
import  Page1  from './Page1'
import  Page2  from './Page2'
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Page1"
        drawerStyle={{width: '60%'}}
        drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerMenu {...props} />}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Page1" component={Page1} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Page2" component={Page2} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

package.json

```
 "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.14.5",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.2",
    "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.3.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.11.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "mobx": "^6.1.4",
    "mobx-react": "^7.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-modalize": "^2.0.8",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.16.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "reanimated-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Check how you are using (importing) the app.js in the index.js